# Creating text file using stream but not writing to disk

Tags: c#, stream

How can I create an html file in memory given some text,then name the file, create its content type then put it in a stream without writing to the device, I would just need the stream.

I am sending the content as a `byte[]` to a web service.

I could use something like this, but i do not want to actually have a physical file but instead just the stream so that i can convert to its byte representation and send it, I do not have a path either.. just not sure how to go about this

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
{
    Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true)
        .GetBytes("<html><p>Some test to save in mycontent.html</p></html>");
    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length); //i do not want to generate the file
}
```

I want the stream to know that the file name is named `mycontent.html`, content type `text/html` and the content to be in stream format or `byte[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a `FileStream`, instead use a `MemoryStream`. For example:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("<html><p>Some test to save in mycontent.html</p></html>");
    ms.Write(info, 0, info.Length); 

    ms.Position = 0;

    //Do something with your stream here
}
```

Note that no stream "knows" what the file name is going to be. You set that metadata as part of the process you use to send it to the client.

Comment: Thanks, can i set the name of the file file somewhere and content type or not possible?

Comment: Well, if you're sending it as part of an HTTP response for example, you would set the `content-disposition`. For example `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.html"`

Comment: yeah so i will be sending an object as ```{ FileName:"some.html", ContentType:"text/html", Content:[some byte[]]```

Comment: Well it depends on your situation, but yes, that might work.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a MemoryStream

```
using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
{
        // Write to stream
        mem.Write(...); 

        // Go back to beginning of stream
        mem.Position = 0;

        // Use stream to send data to Web Service
}
```

Comment: what about giving the file a name and content type?

Comment: @jedgard You need to pass file name and content type to the webservice separately. If you show us your current code version of how you send your file, we can tell you.

Comment: I see so the consuming web service would take the file name, content type and create the file from the stream content.

Answer (score -1):

As soon as you leave the using block’s scope, the stream is closed and disposed. The Close() calls the Flush(). Flush() is exactly what you want to avoid.

Try overriding the Flush() so it does nothing when called.

```
public class MyStream : FileStream 
{
    public override void Flush()
    {
        //Do nothing
        reutrn;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer makes no sense. OP is using `FileStream` in their code, and `Flush` will have no effect on a memory stream.

Comment: @DavidG edited to overrideing the `Flush()`. What do you think?

Comment: I think it's a waste of code because in a `MemoryStream`, flush doesn't do anything anyway. You have misunderstood the question being asked.